iOS - Archiving in Xcode 16
Archiving in Xcode 16
Errors:

Assertion failed: ((ct == Atom::ContentType::objcConst) || (ct == Atom::ContentType::objcData) || (ct == Atom::ContentType::constData) || (ct == Atom::ContentType::constText)), function ObjCClassReadOnlyDataRef, file Atom.cpp, line 3022.
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


including -ld64 in the "other linker flags", solved the assertion failure issue while archiving the app in Xcode 16.0
